# A function that makes an array of length b with all values equal to a, then takes the product (Ruby 2.3.3)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to define a function *power(a,b)* that takes the value **a** and repeats it **b** times and stores it in an array. Then takes the product of that array.

The idea is to be able to take any number **a** and raise it to the power of **b** using arrays.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do that rather than just `a**b`.

Comment: `[a].*(b).inject(:*)`

Comment: "I need to define a function *power(a,b)* that takes the value **a** and repeats it **b** times and stores it in an array." – Then do it! We're not stopping you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
def power(a, b)
  Array.new(b, a).inject(1, :*)
end

power(2, 3)
=> 8
power(2, 4)
=> 16
```

Comment: You don't need the initial value for `reduce`, if omitted it'll use the first value in the array

Comment: Yeah, if the array is empty you obtain nil, not zero

Comment: Eloquent Ruby:)